# Jquery SelectBox CSS not working when Settings for type-to-find are applied

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am using the Claviska Jquery Selectbox and I have already posted an issue on his Github, but have yet to receive a reply and I don't have a lot of time to get this figured out, so I'm hoping someone else can help me with this. I need to have the option of type-to-find - where you can scroll through the select menu depending on which letter of the alphabet you choose. But when I apply the setting for that, the CSS just quits working.

This is the code for the type-to-find:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("SELECT").selectBox('settings', {
        'loopOptions': 'boolean'
    });
});
```

and this is the original code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("SELECT").selectBox();
});
```

There is nothing special about the CSS or the form, it's just a pretty basic state search. but here it is anyway.
HTML FORM:

```
<select name="state" id="state" class="selectBox-dropdown" tabindex="7">
<option value="" selected>&nbsp;</option>
<option value="AL" >Alabama</option>
<option value="AK" >Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ" >Arizona</option>
<option value="AR" >Arkansas</option>
<option value="CA" >California</option>
<option value="CO" >Colorado</option>
<option value="CT" >Connecticut</option>
<option value="DE" >Delaware</option>
<option value="DC" >District Of Columbia</option>
<option value="FL" >Florida</option>
<option value="GA" >Georgia</option>
<option value="GU" >Guam</option>
<option value="HI" >Hawaii</option>
<option value="ID" >Idaho</option>
<option value="IL" >Illinois</option>
<option value="IN" >Indiana</option>
<option value="IA" >Iowa</option>
<option value="KS" >Kansas</option>
<option value="KY" >Kentucky</option>
<option value="LA" >Louisiana</option>
<option value="ME" >Maine</option>
<option value="MD" >Maryland</option>
<option value="MA" >Massachusetts</option>
<option value="MI" >Michigan</option>
<option value="MN" >Minnesota</option>
<option value="MS" >Mississippi</option>
<option value="MO" >Missouri</option>
<option value="MT" >Montana</option>
<option value="NE" >Nebraska</option>
<option value="NV" >Nevada</option>
<option value="NH" >New hampshire</option>
<option value="NJ" >New jersey</option>
<option value="NM" >New mexico</option>
<option value="NY" >New york</option>
<option value="NC" >North carolina</option>
<option value="ND" >North dakota</option>
<option value="OH" >Ohio</option>
<option value="OK" >Oklahoma</option>
<option value="OR" >Oregon</option>
<option value="PW" >Palau</option>
<option value="PA" >Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="PR" >Puerto Rico</option>
<option value="RI" >Rhode Island</option>
<option value="SC" >South Carolina</option>
<option value="SD" >South Dakota</option>
<option value="TN" >Tennessee</option>
<option value="TX" >Texas</option>
<option value="UT" >Utah</option>
<option value="VT" >Vermont</option>
<option value="VI" >Virgin Islands</option>
<option value="VA" >Virginia</option>
<option value="WA" >Washington</option>
<option value="WV" >West Virginia</option>
<option value="WI" >Wisconsin</option>
<option value="WY" >Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you also attach your html?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("SELECT").selectBox('settings', {
    loopOptions : true
   });
});
```

Don't write 'Boolean'  - They write that in the example to let you know the value can be set to true or false

I have not used this plug-in , I don't know if it wants a string Boolean , or actual boolean , try both.

Comment: thank you for the reply, unfortunately that did not work to get the CSS working. It seems to be whenever I add 'settings' after $(SELECT).selectBox is where is breaks.

Comment: Ugh - no, that didn't work either. This is a real mystery to me. I'm no stranger to Jquery or this selectBox plugin, but we've never used any options or settings with it before and I can't understand why that would even have an affect on the CSS, unless there is something in the JS file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think `loopOptions` is not for type-to-find:

`loopOptions [boolean]` - flag to allow arrow keys to loop through options

I didn't find a solution in claviska's plugin, but I found plugin `Select2` may suits your need, see the demo: http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#placeholders

Comment: Thanks, but I don't even see where that plugin has the option to scroll through the list with the keyboard. If I keep typing the same letter - say letter M - it just adds more M's in the text field.

Comment: @nutless_neo Oh. I misunderstood your meaning of type-to-find. In Select2, when you type, it will reduce the dropdown selections to only have the selections that match with what you have typed.